# why is this formula not logically valid?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, predicate-logic

Let a unary predicate $R$ be the only nonlogical symbol of $L$. Then the formula $R(x) \rightarrow(\forall x) R(x)$ is not logically valid. How can I show that?

Comment: Consider $(x=0) \to \forall x (x=0)$

Comment: Isn't the equality a different alphabet of L, it says that R is an unary function symbol and this symbol is the only symbol in the language L and also $0$ is constant but the language has no constant @MauroALLEGRANZA

Comment: It is only a way to focus on the invalidity of the formula. Interpret it in $\mathbb N$ and interpret the symbol $R$ with the property: "it is Even". We have: "if x is Even, then every number is Even". Now is it more clear?

Comment: Yes, nice counter example, thank you so much :)

Answer (score 2):

A formula is logically valid iff all structures and variable assignment functions satisfy the formula, and invalid iff there is at least one counter model + assignment under which it is false.
So to ensure that $R(x)$ is true under a certain assignment and $\forall x R(x)$ false, you just need to define the model such that $R$ is true of one object and false of another one, and specify the relevant variable assignment.

Comment: What do you mean by "$R(x)$ is the negation of $x$"? Objects can't have negations, only formulas can. You don't even need to think of a "meaningful" interpretation for the symbol $R$, you just need to define it such that the formula becomes false. This can be achieved by defining the interpretation of $R$ to include one element and another one not.

Comment: you're right, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

Consider a domain $\{a,b\}$ where $R(a)$ and $\lnot R(b)$ are true.

What is the truth value of $R(a) \to \forall x . R(x)$?

---

I hope this helps ^_^